# parent-child json from csv using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to use Python to turn data from a CSV into a JSON having parent-child transformation. I am able to make it according to the columns specified in my .csv file but I want something more to be added which can be a metadata to the node, or the header of the csv file can be as metadata.

my text.csv

```
Team,Task,Country,ID,ID2
Team C,Processing,US,67,34
Team C,Review,US,734,56
Team C,Support,US,34,43
```

I want the following output:

```
{"name": "flare", 
 "test": "flare",
    "children": 
    [ 
        {
            "name": "Team C",
            "test": "TEAM",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Processing",
                "test": "Task",
                "children": [{
                "name": "US",
                "test": "[ID: 67, ID2: 34]",
                "size": 1983
            },   
            {
                "name": "Review",
                "test": "Task",
                "size": 1675
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Support",
                "test": "Task",
                "size": 2042
            },
            ]
        },  
        ]
    }, 
    ]
};
```

---

**Python Code:**

```
import csv
import json
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, size=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.size = size

    def child(self, cname, size=None):
        child_found = [c for c in self.children if c.name == cname]
        if not child_found:
            _child = Node(cname, size)
            self.children.append(_child)
        else:
            _child = child_found[0]
        return _child

    def as_dict(self):
        res = {'name': self.name}
        if self.size is None:
            res['children'] = [c.as_dict() for c in self.children]
        else:
            res['size'] = self.size
        return res
root = Node('Flare')

with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        grp1, grp2, grp3, size = row
        root.child(grp1).child(grp2).child(grp3, size)

print json.dumps(root.as_dict(), indent=4)
```

---

where "test" is some data that I want to be printed in the .json. Kindly help me for the same. Stuck and wasted many hours but couldn't find any.
TIA :)

Comment: Post your code,

Comment: Joao Vitorino  please bear with the code identation

Comment: How are you determining `test`?

Comment: This variable test will be further used as a hover value when this JSON will be put to a collapsible tree which is made using D3js

Comment: Should I post the D3.js code also if u want any reference for the same ... Edward Minnix

Answer (score 0):

Additional information could be passed to each child by adding another optional argument to your child, e.g. `extra`. This could be in the form of a dictionary, and if present is added to the child's dictionary. For example:

```
import csv
import json

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, size=None, extra=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.size = size
        self.extra = extra

    def child(self, cname, size=None, extra=None):
        child_found = [c for c in self.children if c.name == cname]
        if not child_found:
            _child = Node(cname, size, extra)
            self.children.append(_child)
        else:
            _child = child_found[0]
        return _child

    def as_dict(self):
        res = {'name': self.name}
        if self.size is None:
            res['children'] = [c.as_dict() for c in self.children]
        else:
            res['size'] = self.size

        if self.extra:
            res.update(self.extra)

        return res

root = Node('Flare')

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        team, task, country, id, id2 = row
        root.child(team, extra={'test' : 'TEAM'}) \
            .child(task, extra={'test' : 'Task'}) \
            .child(country, extra={'test' : {'ID': id, 'ID2': id2}}) \
            .child(id, size=id2)

print json.dumps(root.as_dict(), indent=4)
```

This would give you:

```json
{
    "name": "Flare", 
    "children": [
        {
            "test": "TEAM", 
            "name": "Team C", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "test": "Task", 
                    "name": "Processing", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "test": {
                                "ID2": "34", 
                                "ID": "67"
                            }, 
                            "name": "US", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "67", 
                                    "size": "34"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "test": "Task", 
                    "name": "Review", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "test": {
                                "ID2": "56", 
                                "ID": "734"
                            }, 
                            "name": "US", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "734", 
                                    "size": "56"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "test": "Task", 
                    "name": "Support", 
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "test": {
                                "ID2": "43", 
                                "ID": "34"
                            }, 
                            "name": "US", 
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "34", 
                                    "size": "43"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You should be able to adjust the call to include the information you want and the layout you want. These are examples.